# UNION types character varying and date cannot be matched

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a query below that runs perfectly fine until I include the "activity_retailers" union to which it will return the error. From my understanding, one of the varchars and date is conflicting, however I have checked and can't seem to locate any dates with conflicting data types. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
with date_variables as (select 
    '2021-01-01'::date as all_start,
    '2021-12-31'::date as all_end),
earn_txn as (select
    shop_id,
    state,
    date__date as "date",
    extract(year from pin.date__date) as "year",
    extract(month from pin.date__date) as "month",
    transactiontype,
    row_number() over (order by shop_id) as transactionid,
    'India' as countryname
from
    (select * from dw_yc_in.purchase_in as u join dw_global_app.in_shop_user as s on u.retailer_id = s.user_id) pin
where
    transactiontype in ('purchase',)
),
burn_txn as (select
    shop_id,
    state,
    transaction_date as "date",
    extract(year from rin.transaction_date) as "year",
    extract(month from rin.transaction_date) as "month",
    'Redemptions' as transactiontype,
    row_number() over (order by shop_id) as transactionid,
    'India' as countryname
from
    (select * from dw_yc_in.redemption_in as u join dw_global_app.in_shop_user as s on u.retailer_id = s.user_id) rin
where
    status in ('approved', 'redeemed')
),
onboarded_retailers_mvp as (
    select shop_id,
    state,
    shop_updated_date as "date",
    extract(year from a.shop_updated_date)  as "year",
    extract(month from a.shop_updated_date) as "month",
      'shop_setup' as transactiontype,
    row_number() over (order by shop_id) as transactionid,
        'India' as countryname      
    from 
    (select * from dw_yc_in.india_users_migrated as u join dw_global_app.in_shop_user as s on u.retailer_id = s.user_id) a
    where tag_name='mart'
    and is_shop_setup='yes'
    and status in ('approved') 
),
order_retailers as (
    select shop_id,
    state,
    order_update_date as "date",
    extract(year from e.order_update_date)  as "year",
    extract(month from e.order_update_date) as "month", 'shop_orders' as transactiontype,
    row_number() over (order by shop_id) as transactionid, 'India' as countryname
    from (select * from dw_yc_in.mp_in_order_report as u join dw_global_app.in_shop_user as s on u.retailer_id = s.user_id) e
),
activity_retailers as (
    select 
        shop_id::varchar(513) AS shop_id, 
        final_created_at as "date",
        extract(year from final_created_at)  as "year",
        extract(month from final_created_at) as "month", 
        'in_app_activity' as transactiontype,
        state,
        row_number() over (order by shop_id) as transactionid, 
        country::varchar(513) as countryname
    from (
        with f1 as (
            select *, to_char(to_date(created_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')::date as final_created_at,
            coalesce (nullif(trim(userid), ''), nullif(trim(json_extract_path_text(properties, 'userId', true)), '')) as user_id_final,
            (case when coalesce(nullif(trim(userid), ''), nullif(trim(json_extract_path_text(properties, 'userId', true)), '')) is not null then 'not null'
                else 'null' end) as user_id_availability,
            nullif(trim(json_extract_path_text(properties, 'country', true)), '') as country
            from all_events.rudder_events
            where event like 'a_%'
        and event not like 'a_Onboarding%'
        and event not like 'a_Splash%'
        and user_id_availability = 'not null'
        and country notnull 
        )
        select country::varchar(513), shop_id::varchar(513), final_created_at, state
        from f1 as u
        join dw_global_app.in_shop_user s
        on u.user_id_final = s.user_id
        join dw_yc_in.india_users_migrated f
        on f.retailer_id = s.user_id)
)
select countryname, state, count (distinct shop_id)
from (select * from earn_txn
union all select * from burn_txn
union all select * from onboarded_retailers_mvp
union all select * from order_retailers
union all select * from activity_retailers)
where "date" between (select all_start from date_variables) and (select all_end from date_variables)
group by countryname, state
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using UNION on several CTEs, each CTE would need to provide the same data type in the matching columns. The error is saying that one CTE is providing a text column in the same position that another CTE is providing a Date column.

For example, the first `order_retailers` CTE is defined as:

```sql
order_retailers as (
    select shop_id,
    state,
```

Clearly, `state` is a text field.

Then, the UNION is adding the `activity_retailers` CTE:

```sql
activity_retailers as (
    select 
        shop_id::varchar(513) AS shop_id, 
        final_created_at as "date",
```

The second field is a Date field, that is very different from the `State` field, which is text.

It would appear that you are missing the `State` field in the `activity_retailers` CTE.